# jQuery event specific to a video element

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, video, plugins

I am trying to make custom video controls for a bootstrap plugin and I am having trouble with making the jQuery more detailed. The actual jQuery code works, but I need to be able to make the jQuery have some section to it that allows multiple instances of that video to be in a page so that the plug-in is easier to use and has less restrictions.

So far, this is what I have:

```
window.onload = function() {

// Video
var video = document.getElementById("video");

// Buttons
var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
var muteButton = document.getElementById("mute");
var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen");

// Sliders
var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
var volumeBar = document.getElementById("volume-bar");


// Event listener for the play/pause button
$(playButton).click(function() {
    if (video.paused == true) {
        // Play the video
        video.play();
        // Update the button text to 'Pause'
        $(playButton).removeClass("glyphicon-play").addClass("glyphicon-pause");
    } else {
        // Pause the video
        video.pause();
        // Update the button text to 'Play'
        $(playButton).removeClass("glyphicon-pause").addClass("glyphicon-play");
    }
});

// play if video is clicked
$(video).click(function() {
    if (video.paused == true) {
        // Play the video
        video.play();
        // Update the button text to 'Pause'
        $(playButton).removeClass("glyphicon-play").addClass("glyphicon-pause");
    } else {
        // Pause the video
        video.pause();
        // Update the button text to 'Play'
        $(playButton).removeClass("glyphicon-pause").addClass("glyphicon-play");
    }
});
// Event listener for the mute button
$(muteButton).click(function() {
    if (video.muted == false) {
        // Mute the video
        video.muted = true;
        // Update the button text
        $(muteButton).removeClass("glyphicon-volume-up").addClass("glyphicon-volume-off");
    } else {
        // Unmute the video
        video.muted = false;
        // Update the button text
        $(muteButton).removeClass("glyphicon-volume-off").addClass("glyphicon-volume-up");
    }
});
// Event listener for the full-screen button
$(fullScreenButton).click(function() {
if (video.requestFullscreen) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
    }
});
// Event listener for the seek bar
$(seekBar).change(function() {
// Calculate the new time
    var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
    // Update the video time
    video.currentTime = time;
});
// Update the seek bar as the video plays
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    // Calculate the slider value
    var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;
    // Update the slider value
    seekBar.value = value;
});
// Event listener for the volume bar
$(volumeBar).change(function() {
    // Update the video volume
    video.volume = volumeBar.value;
});
}
```

This is all that I have for the jQuery so far and the basic html for the video is as follows:

```
<div id="video-container">
    <!-- Video -->
    <video id="video" width="640" height="365" poster="pictures\MCR-Logo.png">
      <source src="videos\MCR-TheLightBehindYourEyes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <!-- Video Controls -->
    <div id="video-controls">
        <button type="button" id="play" class="play glyphicon glyphicon-play btn"></button>
        <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0" max="100">
        <button type="button" id="mute" class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up btn"></button>
        <input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1">
        <button type="button" id="full-screen" class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen btn"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I basically just need to know how to make it possible to have multiple video  elements in ran off of one jQuery file, and more importantly, be in only a section of the file because the rest of it will need to have the code for the other functions of the plug-in. Any help in this will be extremely valuable to me and i need to know how to finish this very quickly so that i can get to work on the other sections of the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to have multiple instances in the same page, the first step would be to move from the `id` attribute and start using classes.

```
<div class="video-container">
    <!-- Video -->
    <video class="video" width="640" height="365" poster="pictures\MCR-Logo.png">
      <source src="videos\MCR-TheLightBehindYourEyes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <!-- Video Controls -->
    <div class="video-controls">
        <button type="button" class="play" class="play glyphicon glyphicon-play btn"></button>
        <input type="range" class="seek-bar" value="0" max="100">
        <button type="button" class="mute" class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up btn"></button>
        <input type="range" class="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="full-screen" class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen btn"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you can make use of the `jQuery.each()` function to make a loop on all elements in the page and then run your code for every element.

See the following snippet that uses the `jQuery.each()` function. In every loop, the `$item` is a jQuery object of the current `div.video-container` element.

Then you can use `jQuery.find()` to find the control buttons and the `video` element.

The rest of the code is pretty much the same, the only changed I made is to re-use the jQuery selectors, there is a (small in your case) performance gain.

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('.video-container').each(function(idx, item) {
        var $item = $(item);

        // Video
        var video = $item.find(".video")[0];

        // Buttons
        var $playButton = $item.find(".play");
        var $muteButton = $item.find(".mute");
        var $fullScreenButton = $item.find(".full-screen");

        // Sliders
        var $seekBar = $item.find(".seek-bar");
        var $volumeBar = $item.find(".volume-bar");

        // Event listener for the play/pause button
        $playButton.click(function() {
            if (video.paused == true) {
                // Play the video
                video.play();
                // Update the button text to 'Pause'
                $playButton.removeClass("glyphicon-play").addClass("glyphicon-pause");
            } else {
                // Pause the video
                video.pause();
                // Update the button text to 'Play'
                $playButton.removeClass("glyphicon-pause").addClass("glyphicon-play");
            }
        });

        // play if video is clicked
        $(video).click(function() {
            if (video.paused == true) {
                // Play the video
                video.play();
                // Update the button text to 'Pause'
                $playButton.removeClass("glyphicon-play").addClass("glyphicon-pause");
            } else {
                // Pause the video
                video.pause();
                // Update the button text to 'Play'
                $playButton.removeClass("glyphicon-pause").addClass("glyphicon-play");
            }
        });
        // Event listener for the mute button
        $muteButton.click(function() {
            if (video.muted == false) {
                // Mute the video
                video.muted = true;
                // Update the button text
                $muteButton.removeClass("glyphicon-volume-up").addClass("glyphicon-volume-off");
            } else {
                // Unmute the video
                video.muted = false;
                // Update the button text
                $muteButton.removeClass("glyphicon-volume-off").addClass("glyphicon-volume-up");
            }
        });
        // Event listener for the full-screen button
        $fullScreenButton.click(function() {
        if (video.requestFullscreen) {
            video.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
            } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
            }
        });
        // Event listener for the seek bar
        $seekBar.change(function() {
        // Calculate the new time
            var time = video.duration * ($seekBar.val() / 100);
            // Update the video time
            video.currentTime = time;
        });
        // Update the seek bar as the video plays
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
            // Calculate the slider value
            var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;
            // Update the slider value
            $seekBar.val(value);
        });
        // Event listener for the volume bar
        $volumeBar.change(function() {
            // Update the video volume
            video.volume = volumeBar.val();
        });
    });
};
```

**Note**: One more thing I would change is to add to your classes (your IDs in your sample) a prefix so that they are unique and avoid being used in some other CSS style. For example instead of `.play` you could use `.bsvideo-play`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried using classes but could not figure out how to integrate them. Also i will take your advice on the unique classes.

Comment: Glad I helped! If you want, take a look here, you can read how you could make it as a jQuery plugin https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff608209. It will be useful if you want to add different options per video.